# How to grab part of JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
            this.on('success', function(file, responseText) { 
                var theID = JSON.stringify(responseText);
                alert(theID);

                window.location.href = ('want to put something here');    

            });
```

The alert is giving me:

{"message":"success","fileID":399}

and I would like to grab the fileID value, which in this case would be 399.
Thank you.

Comment: `responseText.fileID`

Comment: If is a `JSON` object than `text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
window.location.href = responseText.fileID;
```

will do since responseText is already JSON

Answer (score 1):

```
this.on('success', function(file, responseText) { 
            var theID = JSON.stringify(responseText);
            alert(theID);

            if(responseText.fileID == 399) {
                // Do something
            }
            window.location.href = ('want to put something here');    

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If responseText is already in JSON format, then :

```
   responseText.fileID
```

if it is in String format, then first parse it:

```
var json = JSON.parse(responseText);
alert(json.fileID);
```